# Como usar o Z3 da Microsoft em java?

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um trabalho em que preciso integrar o [Z3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/z3m/) da Microsoft ao java

Alguém sabe como fazer isso, tipo um passo a passo?

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/master/examples/java

Answer (score 0):

Tanto ***Scala*** quanto Java podem ser integrados com ***Z3***.

Lembrando que Scala é uma das linguagens que rodam na **Java Virtual Machine**

http://lara.epfl.ch/w/ScalaZ3

Para Java, o próprio Leonardo Moura tem esse pequeno passo-a-passo:
https://leodemoura.github.io/blog/2012/12/10/z3-for-java.html

Não pude encontrar mais além desses.